# script: Check if all the file of a directory contains a particular string then send mail with name of that file in linux bash script

Tags: shell, sh

I have to write a script that is going to check whether all the files of a directory contains a particular string if yes then send the mail with that file name.

Let me explain this in more depth.  Suppose I have a directory `/demo/`, this directory contains 4 files named as:

1. `file1`
2. `file2`
3. `file3`
4. `file4`

Now the string I am looking for is `"some text"` and `"some text2"`, if any file contains any one of the string then mail should be sent. Suppose `file1` contains `"some text"` and `file3` contains `"some text2"` then mail should be sent like:

```
Alert check file1

Alert check file2
```

Different mail for both the files.

Now I think I have to use this command:

```
grep -rnw '/demo/' -e 'some text', 'some text2'
```

But I am not sure how to check for my conditions, so is there any way to achieve this?

For mail I am using `sendmail` service, but I am more worried about my conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The command to look for two regular expressions with `grep` is `grep -e 'some text' -e 'some text2'`.  Probably more idiomatically use `grep -E` and a single regex.  Replace `-n` with `-l` to only print the file names.

```
grep -E 'some text|some text2' -lrw /demo/ |
while read -r filename; do
    sendmail -oi -t <<____
Subject: Alert for $filename
To: you@example.net

Alert check $filename
____
done
```

This only works correctly if your file names don't contain newlines. If you need to cope with completely arbitrary file names, probably look into `find -exec`.